# Propertybinding combobox setting items does not appear to be an option

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am doing this in Windows Form Application using C#. In my research I have come across the PropertyBinding options which seems to be what I want to do.

What I am trying to do is use the Application Settings | PropertyBinding options to set my combobox items. The reason being is I want to use a config file to update my products and versions in a settings file rather than rebuilding my solution each time I add a new product/version (have it read from a list in a flat file for the options).

I do not see an option for items in the list so it makes me wonder if this is possible or if anyone would have any suggestions on how to accomplish this. I would even accept the proper terms so I can search for the solution myself as an answer.

Comment: A comobobox! I love that control. In seriousness though, WPF and Windows Forms are two completely different technologies, which are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, its just windows form application. The tutorial before hand was WPF (edited my article to match)

Comment: In that case, you should be sure to check out a winforms tutorial. While similar, winforms and wpf are fairly different in practice.

Comment: Yeah I have my form built and functioning to do exactly what I want now. So the tutorials i have done were a mix of both WPF and forms i guess. Just messed up the terms is all. All i need to figure out now is to change my combobox items via a file and though the propertybinding setting was what I would need but do not see "items" as an option like i do in the normal property windows... I could not find any tutorials with what i am trying to accomplish :(

Comment: Post the code you've tried

Comment: Well there was no code because I tried to do it this way:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6.aspx

However, the Items option was not available. So what I am looking for is either the right search terms to search for so I can figure this out on my own, or hopefully i just need to pick a different option in the propertyBinding's section that I am unaware of. I am completely brand new to visual studios and c#.